# Read csv that contains array of string in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to read a csv that has the following data:

```
name,date,win,stops,cost
a,2020-1-1,true,"[""x"", ""y"", ""z""]", 2.3
b,2021-3-1,true,, 1.3
c,2023-2-1,true,"[""x""]", 0.3
d,2021-3-1,true,"[""z""]", 2.3
```

using inferSchema results in the stops field spilling over to the next columns and messing up the dataframe

If I give my own schema like:

```
    schema = StructType([
    StructField('name', StringType()),
    StructField('date', TimestampType()),
    StructField('win', Booleantype()),
    StructField('stops', ArrayType(StringType())),
    StructField('cost', DoubleType())])
```

results in this exception:

`pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: CSV data source does not support array<string> data type.`

so how would I properly read the csv without this failure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since csv doesn't support array, you need to first read as string, then convert it.

```py
# You need to set escape option to ", since it is not the default escape character (\). 
df = spark.read.csv('file.csv', header=True, escape='"')

df = df.withColumn('stops', F.from_json('stops', ArrayType(StringType())))
```

Comment: This worked so well. Can you explain the code though? Thankyou.

Comment: Sure, which part is confusing you?

Comment: The part where we added escape. I was not using escape before and one of the string columns was being cut-off.  Does this convert it into json and then we are reading json back to string using from_json?

Comment: OP's csv has `"[""x""]"` in on of the column. string column with a special characters have to be wrapped with double quote, and then if you want to have a literal double quote between the wrapping quotes, you need to escape it. Most common escape would be using \ like `"[\"x\"]"`.  This is the default character, so doing `spark.read.csv` without escape option, it will read as string value `["x"]`.  However, OP's example is `"[""x""]"`, so I need to set escape option to `"` and this will read as string value `["x"]`.

Comment: After the first line, `["x"]` is a **string** value because csv does not support array column. In order to convert this to Array of String, I use `from_json` on the column to convert it.  `from_json` takes string JSON and convert it to JSON object which can take a form of object or array.  hope this makes sense but let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score -2):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()


dataframe = spark.read.options(header='True', delimiter=",").csv("file_name.csv")

dataframe.printSchema()
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: updated the code a bit to serve better purpose.

Comment: There's syntax error in your code and no, it doesn't help. now even the column names aren't read properly. everything is a string and columns names are _c1, _c2 and so on.

Comment: what's the error? can you share?

Comment: delimiter='," mismatching quotes.

Comment: try above code now

Comment: like I said< above " it doesn't help. now even the column names aren't read properly. everything is a string and columns names are _c1, _c2 and so on."

Comment: You can't save a dataframe which contains column with array/struct type to CSV. You need to cast the `stops` column to string before writing. ```df.withColumn('stops', col('stops').cast('string')).write.csv('path')
```

Comment: data comes from outside. can't control the incoming format. And I'm trying to read it, not write.

Comment: then write `read` instead of `write`. Anyway, Good Luck!